# Pass the array list to the WCF application

Tags: web-services, wcf

I am new to WCF.
I have a scenario where i have [image: Error while passing ArrayList].

When i am trying to pass the array list it giving the error.
Please, have the look to image.

**ICommissionService Definition**

```
[GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "FPCommission.ICommissionService")]
public interface ICommissionService
{
   [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/ICommissionService/GetCommisionResponse",
                      ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/ICommissionService/GetCommisionResponseResponse")]
   object[] GetCommisionResponse(object[] loc_);
}
```

I am still not get the solution.

Comment: can you post the definition of ICommissionService together with any data types?

Comment: Why are you still using the ArrayList class from .NET 1.1?

Comment: @Richard: I hav edited my question and post the definition of ICommissionService.  Please, hav a look...

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the Service reference, you should set the CollectionType to System.Collections.Arraylist - if you use the UI it's in the Advanced section, if you use svcutil.exe it's the /ct switch

There's a lot more information in [Collections in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem, from the service:

```
object[] GetCommisionResponse(object[] loc_);
```

What you've told WCF here is that you're going to be returning an array of Object. Because of that, the client expects to get back an array of Object. That of course is not what you're actually giving it.

Subclasses don't work the same way in WCF that they work elsewhere. You have to explicitly define in the service what you're returning, because the client has to know what to expect and create classes for.

So if you're actually returning an array of Flight, change it to this:

```
Flight[] GetCommisionResponse(object[] loc_);
```

But if you're returning something and some subclasses of itself, you'll have to use the [KnownType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

```
[KnownType(typeof(FlightSubClass))]
Flight[] GetCommisionResponse(object[] loc_);
```

You can do the same thing on the Interface using [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx), and only have to do it once.

Comment: I am not even able to pass the ArrayList to the service..Please tell me wat i have to do

Comment: It's going to be the same problem only on the parameter instead of the return type. It expects an array of Object and you're passing it something else. You need to change the definition of the service to tell it what you're really trying to pass in.

Comment: What is the type that's actually in your array list? Change the Object[] above to that type, and it'll work. (So if it's an array of contacts, use Contact[]).

Comment: @Tridus: But how can i do this "Change the Object[] above to that type"

Comment: Open up the service file in Visual Studio and edit it? I don't understand the question, it's just a text file. You edit it like any other file.