# send the ArrayList to the WCF service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass the array list to the WCF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421272/pass-the-array-list-to-the-wcf-application)

Hi friends,

i am facing the problem when send the ArrayList to the WCF service.

Please help how can i send the ArrayList to the WCF service..

[This is the same Q i have posted b4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421272/pass-the-array-list-to-the-wcf-application)
Please Help..

Comment: If it's the same question as you posted before, you should update that one instead.